# Using Boost-Regex to parse string into characters and numerals

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex

I'd like to use Boost's Regex library to separate a string containing labels and numbers into tokens. For example `'abc1def002g30'` would be separated into `{'abc','1','def','002','g','30'}`. I modified the [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_token_iterator.html#id886082) given in Boost documentation to come up with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    string s,str;
    int count;
    do{
        count=0;
        if(argc == 1)
        {
            cout << "Enter text to split (or \"quit\" to exit): ";
            getline(cin, s);
            if(s == "quit") break;
        }
        else
            s = "This is a string of tokens";

        boost::regex re("[0-9]+|[a-z]+");
        boost::sregex_token_iterator i(s.begin(), s.end(), re, 0);
        boost::sregex_token_iterator j;
        while(i != j)
        {
            str=*i;
            cout << str << endl;
            count++;
            i++;
        }
        cout << "There were " << count << " tokens found." << endl;

    }while(argc == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

The number of tokens stored in `count` is correct. However, `*it` contains only an empty string so nothing is printed. Any guesses as to what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: as per the fix suggested below, I modified the code and it now works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs on the sregex_token_iterator:

Effects: constructs a regex_token_iterator that will enumerate one string for each regular expression match of the expression re found within the sequence [a,b), using match flags m (see match_flag_type). The string enumerated is the sub-expression submatch for each match found; **if submatch is -1, then enumerates all the text sequences that did not match the expression** re (that is to performs field splitting)

Since your regex matching all items (unlike the sample code, which only matched the strings), you get empty results.

Try replacing it with a 0.

Comment: Thank you, I should have paid more attention to what that submatch parameter does.

Comment: No problem - please check this as the answer if it worked, or follow-up here if it didn't.  Have fun!